# Issue with Intel Killer WiFi 7 1750 and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: iwlwifi

The Intel Killer Wifi 7 1750 (BE200) of the laptop Dell XPS 13 9340 is not stable with Ubuntu 22.04. It works a very little. But after starting downloading any thing, the system hangs. Is this hardware too new? Do I need to wait for getting it supported?